# WTL CListViewCtrl getSelectedItem is causing an Assertion fail for me

Tags: c++, atl, wtl

This is my code in order to get the name of the item which has been selected in my CListViewCtrl:

```
LVITEM item = { LVIF_PARAM };
CString itemText;

clistViewCtrl.GetSelectedItem(&item);

clistViewCtrl.GetItemText(item.iItem, item.iSubItem, itemText);
```

Note that this code is working. I recently did another project, where I grabbed the name in exactly this way, however, I had no problems there with any assertion fails.

When I execute this with my current project, I always get a debug assertion:

```
"File: ... atlctrls.h"
Line: 3242

Expression: (GetStyle() & 0x0004) != 0
```

Even though the expression already states it pretty much, here is the line causing the failure:

```
ATLASSERT((GetStyle() & LVS_SINGLESEL) != 0);
```

I have barely any idea what the problem is. As I said, the exact same code worked on my other project, and I just went through both, trying to find any differences which could cause this behaviour, but nothing caught my eye.

Honestly, I don't even know if this is related to my code at all, considering the two compared elements seem to be predefined.

My first guess would have been that this part is being called before the items are created, but all items in the listview are created at the point I try to call this code passage.

Can anyone point me to a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your control is not created with style flag `LVS_SINGLESEL`. So calling `GetSelectedItem` is causing an assert. In case of multi selection use `GetFirstSelectedItem` and `GetNextSelectedItem` instead of `GetSelectedItem`. For single selection you can continue useing `GetSelectedItem`, but you have to add `LVS_SINGLESEL` style flag to your control.

Comment: Thank you so much! That works! How could I ever have figured that out on my own....